# Won't boot after inserting new RAM sticks

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, power-supply, power

I bought a new pair of 4GB RAM sticks today.

Thinking it'd be easy to install, I powered down, slapped them in and powered on. It wouldn't boot. The fans spin up, a couple of seconds pass then it powers off, and powers on again and tries again, repeating.

I went out of my way to try to find the exact same sticks as my old ones, so compatibility shouldn't be the issue here.

Specs :

- mobo: Gigabyte GA-Z68AP-D3
- PSU: Silver Power SP-SS750M 750W
- RAM: Corsair Value S. DDR3 1333MHz 4GB CL9 x2

and the 2 new ones are also Corsair Value Select DDR3 1333MHz 4GB CL9's

Just in case any of these other specs are somehow relevant:

- Main drive: Corsair 120GB SSD
- Secondary drive: Seagate 2TB HDD
- GPU: GTX 670
- CPU: Core i7-3770K

Answer marked as duplicate has no answers that helped me fix this.
I'm confused.

Still haven't figured this one out.

I've now tried:

- Unplugging the system and taking out the motherboard CMOS battery and replacing it.
- Running only 1 stick of RAM in all of the slots, all work fine.
- Running only the 2 new RAM sticks, they work fine.
- Mixing 1 of the old RAM sticks with 1 new stick, it works fine.

Anything 3 sticks or more just won't boot.

I've also tried setting it down to 1066 in BIOS and then putting all the RAM sticks in and rebooting. It still won't boot.

Is this a motherboard issue? It seems it just won't let me run any more than 2 sticks of RAM. The specs say it's compatible with up to 32GB, but maybe my board is faulty.

Comment: Generally in a situation like this and your right compatibility shouldn't be an issue you need to rule out a dead DIMM. I would start by putting each DIMM in one by one in to the first slot and check if any of the four cause the machine to have the same symptoms.

Comment: Attempted putting one of the new sticks into 1 of the 2 open(white) slots alternately, it wouldn't power up.
However, attempted putting the 2 new sticks into the 2 previously used(blue) slots, it powered up fine. (Replacing the old ones with the new ones)

I don't think it's the sticks, has to be the slots? Or something.

Comment: Added new information. Linked "Duplicate" has no answer for this question.